# How to: 2 Bvh files, 1 model

Tags: bvh

I have a model. I would like it to have 2 different animations standing upright, and both facing forward in the animation library. How do I do that?

I am using makehuman, blender 2.78, makewalk and fragmotion and bvh hacker. And some x , y , Z things keep getting mixed up when importing to and from the diffrent programs and it also screws with animations.

Can someone please send me this model back all set up and tell me how they did that?

I know it sounds quite simple, but it turned out to be difficult. I would like someone to send the file back so i know it can be done.

Blender seems to be incapable of doing what I am attempting to do. Which is sad I Like this program.

[Model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rit2jet1h4y3n0w/1.mhx2?dl=0)

[bvh file 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjdbltyzlln4rxi/backflip.bvh?dl=0)

[bvh file 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/woq6m3k6waeljdw/idle%20test.bvh?dl=0)